# $\sin(2x) + (1/2)\sin(4x) = a$. Solve for x in terms of a.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am a student teacher and we are doing a project with rockets, solving for the correct angle to launch and hit a target at a designated distance.

However, I find myself stuck with this equation:

$$\sin(2x) + \frac{1}{2}\sin(4x) = a$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Making it so that you only have $2x$ to care about instead of $2x$ and $4x$ in the sine functions is almost never wrong. Does that make things easier?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$a=4\sin x\cos^3x$$

$$a(1+t^2)^2=4t$$ where $t=\tan x$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari.27s_solution